# removable singularity for f with Re f > 0.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$,  $f\in H(D)$. Suppose $Re f(z) > 0$, for all $z\in D$, show that $0$ is removable singularity of $f$.

---

I thought $Re f(z) > 0$ is equivalent with $|f-2i|<|f+2i|$, so $g=(f-2i)/(f+2i)$ is bounded and holomorphic on D (RIGHT OR WRONG?). Then $f=2i(g+1)/(g-1)$, $f(0)=2i(g(0)+1)/(g(0)-1)$. So 0 removable?

Is that right way to do this?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic and real on a connected open set in $\mathbb C$, then $f$ is constant, isn't it? This follows, for example, from the open mapping theorem.

Comment: yeah, of course that is right. but why f is real?

Comment: Uh...you're right, it isn't. I misread the question, and pretty badly at that. My bad.

Comment: that's nothing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(z)=e^{-f(z)}$. What is $|g(z)|$?

Comment: |g|<1. But g(z) may not be holomorphic at 0?

Comment: $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: i know 0 can not be pole, but why 0 can not be identical singularity of g?

Comment: Because of [Riemann's Theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).